# React Native - Android TV - DPad Functionality

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-play-console

I have published a react native application to google play store for android tv.

For tv, I have received notification for:

> **Missing DPad functionality**
>   Your app requires user interaction for
>   menus or app navigation. Please make sure that all menus and app
>   navigation are fully functional using a DPad. Please refer to our DPAD
>   Control and Hardware Declaration documentation.

How do we enable d-pad navigation for react-native android apps?

If you need any more info, just let me know.

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue. Did you get the answer. Please share the solution.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya still same issue. Will be trying out few things tonight. Will let you know if I succeed.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have fixed the issue with d-pad navigation and banner for react-native android tv application.

The issues were: (this includes issues which were not even part of the question)

**1. No full-size app banner**

***Fix:*** `create a folder called drawable` under `"your-app/android/app/src/main/res"`, add a png file **(`dimensions 320px x 180px and 320 dpi`)**, and the most important part is, **`within image, there should be no other text then application name`** with which you have published APK.

**2. Unsupported hardware uses**

***Fix:*** I fixed this issue before posting the question, but if you are facing the issue,

```
refer the answer by **@reidisaki** on this question.
```

**3. Missing DPad functionality (Actual issue raised in the question)**

***Fix:*** I was using InputText on my screen. Well, under `react-native version 0.56` for android/android tv, **`InputText cannot be focused by d-pad`** (directional pad). **`I stopped using TextInput`** and it fixed the d-pad navigation. It is available in the android simulator as well, to test the app.

**To make my application more TV compliant**, in **AndroidManifest.xml** I upgraded my activity launcher to:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

To upgrade theme to leanback for android tv:

1. I **`added leanback library`** to "app-name/android/app/build.gradle" under dependencies section:

   ```
   dependencies {
   ....
   compile "com.android.support:leanback-v17:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
   }
   ```
2. In **AndroidManifest.xml**, I changed theme to **`@style/Theme.Leanback`**

   ```
   <application
     android:name=".MainApplication"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:banner="@drawable/banner"
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
     ....
   </application>
   ```

Comment: Priyank, as you said in point-3 that you stopped using TextInput. What you use to get some data from user on TV devices.

Comment: I used <Text /> component. Created my own on-screen keyboard using buttons, but yeah my requirement of data input was very limited. So it workd for me. Took a variable in state and did the binding with <Text />

Comment: For TextInput, you can place a transparent TouchableOpacity component. On getting focus, force focus to InputText.

Comment: @PriyankThakkar  please help me on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790952/how-to-handle-focus-same-item-when-hardware-back-button-click-in-react-native-fo

Comment: @HemantKaushik please help me on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790952/how-to-handle-focus-same-item-when-hardware-back-button-click-in-react-native-fo

Comment: @TalhaArshad please help me on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790952/how-to-handle-focus-same-item-when-hardware-back-button-click-in-react-native-fo

Comment: I am stuck from last 1 month. and google give the same rejection msg that you are mention in this problem. I have done all steps you give the solution of this problem.

Comment: @PriyankThakkar can you explain with an example how to used <Text/> Component for get input from user on tv device

Answer (score 2):

Did your manifest declare the right uses-features? mainly the first otne touchScreen required false

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
        android:required="false"/>
```

I'm looking to publish an android tv app as well for react native but the focus management for androidtv has bugs namely if you hit the right button but the item is vertically above and to the right android tv does nothing.

edit ------------
have you tried implementing these configurations?

```
<uses-configuration
  android:reqFiveWayNav=["true" | "false"]
  android:reqHardKeyboard=["true" | "false"]
  android:reqKeyboardType=["undefined" | "nokeys" | "qwerty" | "twelvekey"]
  android:reqNavigation=["undefined" | "nonav" | "dpad" | "trackball" | "wheel"]
  android:reqTouchScreen=["undefined" | "notouch" | "stylus" | "finger"] />
```

Comment: Yes, I have removed all these permission by marking the false. Yet the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

I have also come across this problem (and managed to fix)

In my case **Missing Dpad functionality** issue was related to using TextInput component which is not completely supported on AndroidTV yet (can't be focused using DPad)

I fixed it by using a hack to make TextInput focusable. Namely, wrapped it in a touchable (TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity and TouchableHighlight would all work for this purpose) and used the onFocus handler to manage focus on nested TextInput component.

Something along these lines:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  onFocus={() => {
    textInput && textInput.current.focus(); 
  }}
  >
  <TextInput ref={textInput} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

After the issue with TextInput focus was fixed the app was approved for AndroidTV

Comment: That seems to be working