# how to handle focus same item when hardware back button click in react native for android Tv app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-tv

I am working Android TV App using React Native. i am stuck in focus problem.
I have a problem where the focus when returning back to a screen always goes to the first touchable component and not to the component which triggered the showing of second screen.  help me ?

Comment: Are you using class Component or Functional Component ?

Comment: I am Using functional component

Comment: import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';  => make use of this hook to detect when your screen is focused and then with the help of useEffect you focus on your component. First you assign 1 reference to your component, Second onFocus of the screen use the component-reference  to focus on it.

Comment: Do you want to focus on any Input Field or button ?

Comment: i want to focus on same item when i am back from  next screen

Comment: @Kailash any solution of this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72785921/how-to-focus-on-button-from-second-textinput-using-onsubmiteediting-for-react-na)

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Screen = (props) => {

const referenceComponent = useRef();
let isFocused = useIsFocused();

useEffect(() => {

//Use focus statement here 
//something like - referenceComponent.current.focus(); 

}, [isFocused]);


return <View>
         /** other components **/

        <ComponentToBeFocused ref={referenceComponent}/>

    <View>

}
```

Comment: `focus()` is not a method on focusable refs in React Native. The component should be a TouchableOpacity and focused with `ref.current.setNativeProps({ hasTVPreferredFocus: true })`. However this may not necessarily work depending on if the an item has already been focused on pressing back.